# Search text by pattern - Regular Expressions

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to find some text patterns within my database.
I have a column with job titles (Data Analyst, Data Scientist etc.) and I'm trying to find all records with certain Job Title. I've been using following code:

```
grepl(".*Data.*Analyst.*, data$jobtitle, ignore.case = T)
```

It works very well, however it doesn't cover the opposite order of keywords - 
"analyst data" or "Scientist Data".

Ideally I would love to search for "Data" and "Analyst" regardless the locations of the keywords in the title..

Comment: You could use two regular expressions.

Comment: Try `data[which(grepl(".*Data.*, data$jobtitle, ignore.case = T) | grepl(".*Analyst.*, data$jobtitle, ignore.case = T)),]`

Comment: If you want to check for the presence of either "data" or "analyst", you could do: `grepl("analyst|data",data$jobtitle,ignore.case=T)`

Comment: thanks everyone. I also thought about 2 expressions, but due to the large amount of keywords that I'm using I thought that there could be another way to do it. "Or" wouldn't work in this case, as it would also include irrelevant titles such as "Business Analyst" or "Big data developer " etc.

Comment: If you want to check for the presence of both keywords in any order, try positive lookaheads: `grepl("(?=.*analyst)(?=.*data)",data$jobtitle,perl=T,ignore.case=T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for the presence of both keywords "data" and "analyst" in any order, you can use positive lookaheads:

```
grepl("(?=.*analyst)(?=.*data)",data$jobtitle,perl=T,ignore.‌​case=T)
```

This will return true if both words are present, regardless of their order or the presence of other words:

```
grepl("(?=.*analyst)(?=.*data)",c("Analyst data","Data Analyst","Data scientist","Analyst Science data"),perl=T,ignore.case=T)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```